# Windows 10 python files don't save

Tags: python-3.x, windows, save

I just installed python (3.8) on my new laptop (windows 10) (including install to PATH).
Of course I made a test.py script to test whether everything works properly. After opening this file with IDLE and typing `print('test')` I tried to save and then run. However, when trying to run a pop up opens saying that the file needs to be saved. After clicking ok the pop up closes and nothing happens. I have tried this numerous times to no effect.

When closing the script a pop up opens asking if I want to save before closing. Clicking 'yes' makes the pop up disappear and reappear immediately, which keeps happening until I select 'no'. If I open the file again it is empty.

I think maybe it could be blocked by my security provider (F-secure), but I can't find where the problem would be. I couldn't find anyone who has had the same problem so I am kind of at a loss of what to do, any help would be appreciated immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I was not able to fix the problem with IDLE, however using the spyder IDE I can save and run .py files.

If anyone happens to know a fix I'm still happy to hear it!